# How does date rounding in elasticsearch work, and how does it affect cache churn?

Tags: date, caching, curl, optimization, elasticsearch

So, I was browsing this slideshow on optimizing elasticsearch queries which seemed pretty useful:

https://speakerdeck.com/elasticsearch/query-optimization-go-more-faster-better

and it mentions avoiding cache churn by using something similar to:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_all/_search?search_type=count' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
              "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {"range" : {
                            "@timestamp" : {
                                "gte" : "now/d"
                            }
                        }},
                        {"range" : {
                            "@timestamp" : {
                                "gte" : "now-1h"
                            },
                            "_cache" : false
                        }}
                    ]
                }
              }

        }
    }
}'
```

So, the question is: how does date rounding work?

Specifically, what does now/d actually refer to?  Does that simply equate to "today"?  But, does that mean "today according to my local computer running the query" or "today according to the timezone of the computer running the elasticsearch cluster"?  I guess it's hard to differentiate that since most people run on localhost, or their computer running the elasticsearch cluster is most likely set to the same time zone...  But I guess that's a minor question.

I guess, I see this filtered query to mean: "search all indices - it must be from today, and it must be from within the past hour."  I can see where - "it must be from today" is a filter that should be cached since it can be reused.  The elasticsearch github issues mentions this at https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4947

and I see how it can help with avoiding cache churn, but I was actually thinking it is more useful if it was less than or equal to rather than greater than or equal to such as:

```
"lte" : "now/d"
```

which is to say "search all indices - it must be from today or earlier, and it must be from within the past hour." In my opinion, this makes sense because it makes "today or earlier" a constant end point and allows you to search backwards from that now-stationary time point.  This means that you can use this type of filter combination to avoid cache churn and search in the past rather than being limited to searching things from "today".  However, I am not sure if the lte version still helps to avoid cache churn.  Can anyone clarify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, because dates are in milliseconds we must round them to make them more general and make it more probable that filter results can be reused in some other query. I don't have idea what time it will round to. But it should not matter. It's only important that it's rounding to the same thing so it can be reused by cache.

As the order in which we apply filter matters the sooner we narrow records down the better. Ideally our first filter is a cached one and filters out as much as possible. That's why if we want to get data from the last hour, filtering out everything but today makes sense.

Let's consider first condition you mentioned:

```
record_datetime >= now/d && record_datetime >= now-1h
```

It may seem that the first condition is redundant and could be removed without any side effects. But elastic search benefits from it because it can reuse cached filter data it has stored and execute second filter on much smaller set. Keep in mind that be reversing the order of filters we would lose all the benefits of this redundancy.

As you mentioned this can be used also when looking deeper into past. You could use a filter that throws out everything after some day. For example if we need data from the first week of this year we could do something along the lines:

```
record_datetime >= 01.01.2014 && record_datetime <= 05.01.2014 && other_filters
```

Other filters don't have to be time related. If this will be executed many times only `other_filters` will be fully executed, rest will use cached [bitsets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/).

What's more this approach can be used to any numerical data. For example, before filtering by exact latitude and longitude first filter by some coarse grid or city. We want to make filters as similar as possible between queries.

Not sure If I'm being clear enough :)
There's a nice article about improving performance in ES with filters and the exact technique you're asking is explained [here](https://www.found.no/foundation/optimizing-elasticsearch-searches/#cache-granularity-and-acceleration-filters). There's also a ES official documentation about filter order and caching [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filter_order.html).

Comment: Ahh I see. I guess I was hoping there was some magic way to magically get ElasticSearch to avoid cache churn, but your explanation greatly helps.  It makes sense to just set a hard-coded date as a filter point to re-use and cut off data to speed up the query.